# Hibernate not logging SQL queries fired even after enabling all the properties

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, logging

I have logging enabling using the hibernate properties but still I am not able to see the SQL queries being fired

Here is my Spring configuration code:

```
        @Bean
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
            final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
            em.setDataSource(dataSource());
            em.setPackagesToScan("models");

            final HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
            em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
            em.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());
            return em;
        }
        private Properties hibernateProperties() {
            return new Properties() {
                {
                    setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", hbm2ddlScheme);
                    setProperty("hibernate.dialect", dbDialect);
                    setProperty("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers", "true");
                    setProperty("hibernate.use_sql_comments", "true");
                    setProperty("hibernate.generate_statistics", "true");
                    setProperty("format_sql", formatSQL);
                    setProperty("show_sql", showSQL);
                    setProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory");
                    setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "true");
                    setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", "true");
                    setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries", "true");
                    setProperty("net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName", "myehcache.xml");
                }
            };
        }
```

I do see the session stats though. I also want to see the queries that are being fired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `hibernate.show_sql` and `hibernate.format_sql` instead of `show_sql` and `format_sql`